# Taskwarrior: How to show just the most urgent task

Tags: bash, scripting, sh, taskwarrior

I adore taskwarrior, it seems to be the only management app that you can dial in what you decide is the most urgent. Not just due today, or overdue, but a combination of values.

I want to put the top urgency task in a bunch of scripts and widgets (tmux, top bar etc), but this is the best I can do:

```
task next limit:1 | head -n 4 |tail -n1
```

Which displays the whole line, due dates, cruft and all, like this:

```
 1 2d  H Make widgets 16.5
```

I know about `task _get`, the DOM access, but I can't find the way to use it, or any filter.

**How can I just display the description of the top task? Thanks!**

Comment: The output of `task _get 1.description` is perfect, but that's specifically for task #1...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a one line script to get the ID of the latest, this is assuming that taskwarrior does not change its output format.

```
task _get $(task next limit:1 | tail -n +4 | head -n 1 | sed 's/^ //' | cut -d ' ' -f1).description
```

Comment: OMG amazing, thank you! There was an extra leading newline in that output, so I piped it to `tail -n1`

Answer (score 4):

Make a new report named 'desrc' by adding the following lines to your .taskrc file:

```
report.desrc.columns = description
report.desrc.labels  = Description
report.desrc.sort    = urgency-
```

and then ask for the desrc list:

```
task rc.verbose: limit:1 desrc
```

The rc.verbose: removes headlines and everything else, so no need for head and tail.

Answer (score 0):

You could sure use cut to get only certain elements of that line, separated by tabs. It's a fast coreutil.
Nothing against creating a new report though, just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Awk would also work:

```bash
$ task _get $(task next limit:1 | awk 'NR==4{print $1}').description
```